# Extraction of specific digits using JMeter Regex Expression

Tags: java, jmeter

Is there a way in which I can extract the following using Regular Expression Extractor:-

var = **OQ12RT20171128**

After extraction I only want is **20171128** i.e **from position 7 to last (only digits are considered here)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add $ character to mark the end of string and use 8 last digits: `[\d]{8}$`

See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/11).

Or if you need by 7th character use `var = [\w]{6}(\d+)` see [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/1cKirB/12).